# How can i use the 'environ' variable to save_as an excel invoice in another computer

Tags: vba, environment-variables

If I want to save an invoice in the same folder in a different computer.

My path in my current system is C:\Users\bala\Google Drive\Invoice

I'll also be saving it C:\Users\sanford\Google Drive\Invoice

Heard that environment variables do this job, not sure how to do it.

```
Sub Save_As()
Dim filename As String
Dim msgResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
filename = "C:\Users\bala\Google Drive\Invoice\" & Range("F4") & Range("G4") & "_" & Range("M10")
If Len(Dir(filename)) = 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    MsgBox "Invoice saved successully", vbOKOnly, "INVOICE SAVED"

Else
   msgResponse = MsgBox("Do you want to overwrite?", vbYesNoCancel)
   If msgResponse = vbYes Then
        ActiveSheet.SaveAs filename, FileFormat:=52, CreateBackup:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        MsgBox "Invoice saved successully", vbOKOnly, "INVOICE SAVED"

    Else
       Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: use `Environ("Username")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Environ`-function to get any system variable that is set, eg `Environ("Username")` to get the name of the current user.

However, be aware that the *username* is not always the name of the folder where all the user documents are stored. Therefore, it's better to use `Environ("UserProfile")`. So try:

```
filename = Environ("UserProfile") & "\" & Range("F4") & Range("G4") & "_" & Range("M10")
```